# PSA: Answering your own question on Stack Exchange is encouraged

Tags: discussion, psa, answers, self-answer

We have a help center page asking: [Can I answer my own question?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) The answer is yes.

I'm only making this PSA because recently, I have seen three different occasions in which users were asked why they answered their own question (two of these instances have since been deleted). This may inadvertently mislead users to not answer their own questions.

- [Would a "driving hybrid" be an adequate replacement to a fairway wood?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14870/would-a-driving-hybrid-be-an-adequate-replacement-to-a-fairway-wood#comment23760_14919)
- [Who was the youngest winner of Gagarin Cup?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14887/who-was-the-youngest-winner-of-gagarin-cup#comment23703_14895)
- https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14410/how-to-return-midline-tennis-shots#comment22714_14410

**PSA: Answering your own question on Stack Exchange is encouraged**

Comment: Please note answering your own question is encouraged on SE **only when and only if** the question is on-topic. Don't forget there are so many rep hounds trying to score some rep points by asking and answering his/her own question. What we need to establish first is what scope we will cover.

Comment: @Rathony Do you have a source for that? Is that a documented policy on a different SE site? 1) I don't think that's a problem here. 2) If it's off-topic, then the community will speak accordingly.